# Extracting connected pixels using the idea of Breadth-first search

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to collect a set of pixels between two pixels:start and end point from a skeleton image.
 So the idea is : I start on a position in the image. I put that position in a list. Then in a loop

- I get and remove the point at the beginning of the list and make it black in the current image so it won't be added again.
- I put that point in another list (this is the list that I want).I look at every point around the position and if it is not black, add it to the beginning of the list.
  Then start the loop again.

I have develop a piece of code but the loop ends after adding four or five pixels ,before arriving to the end point.

```
vector<Point> traceLine(Mat img , Point peak)

{

  vector<Point> vect1;
  vector<Point> vect2;
  vect1.push_back(peak);
      while(vect1.size() != 0)
      {
        Point p=vect1[0];
        img.at<uchar>(p.x,p.y)=0;
        vect1.erase(vect1.begin());
        vect2.push_back(p);
        vector<Point> vectN;
        vectN=search8Neighbor(img,p);
        vector<Point>::iterator it;
        it = vect1.begin();
        cout<<vectN.size()<<endl;
              if(vectN.size()!=0)
              {
               for(int i=0;i<vectN.size();i++)
                 vect1.insert(it,vectN[i]);
               }
       }
    return vect2;
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a kind of [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm? That can be done depth-first.

Comment: @larsmans I tried to develop my own flood fill , because floodfill with opencv don't return a list of pixels situed in the curve of a skeleton but it didn't work , so I tried to develop a method using breadth first search , I 'm a newbie with image processing .

Comment: You say "I look at every point around the position and if it is not black, add it to the **beginning** of the list.". But you actually use push_back() to add them to the end of the list. You might like to edit your post so that is is consistent.

Comment: @user2151446 how can I add it the point to the beginning of the list ? may be this is the problem .

Comment: @user2151446 I will use insert and try again.

Comment: No, insert() won't make much difference (actually the traversal order will be changed to depth -first, I think), I was just noting that what you say you do is different to what you actually do, which makes it more difficult for others to help with your problem.

Comment: @user2151446 yes that's true but I didn't know  before now that push_back add elements to the list .